# Grid Search on a pipeline without a predictor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I'm currently working on ML project on Python. I'm trying to have a pipeline that prepares data, selects the top features then runs it through a predictor, something like:

```
SelectPredict = Pipeline([

    ('Prepare', Prepare),
    ('TopFeatureSelector', TopFeatureSelector(k=5)),
    ('SVC', SVC())

])
```

Is it possible to run grid search on a Pipeline without a Predictor as the last estimator? For instance, if I was to have a pipeline where the last estimator was a class that used multiple predictors, and tested them all (seems more optimal than having multiple pipelines one for each predictor). Could I somehow tune such a pipeline using Grid Search?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GridSearchCV will require a scoring function to compare the results from all possible combinations of hyperparameters. If you can think of a way to handle that in your code, then it can be done. Please add some sample code for what you actually want to do and maybe we can help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I managed to figure out how to get the results I needed. I made the following adjustments.  
PrepareSelectPredict = Pipeline([
            ('Prepare', Prepare),
            ('TopFeatureSelector', tfs),
            ('Classifier', model)
        ])  
I use a helper function to iterate through dictionaries of models and their hyperparameters to generate the parameter grid for the pipeline, then I run grid search/rand search 'n' times, 'n' being the number of classifiers.